# Carte cluster on AWS Error : Cannot assign requested address

Tags: jvm, pentaho

Trying to set up Pentaho CE cluster on AWS EC2 Windows instance.

Works well with using private IP. But when i try to use EC2 Instance public IP, I am unable to start the carte service.

java.net.Bind Exception : Cannot assign the requested address: JVM_Bind

I have checked, there is no duplication on this port.
52.34.59.19 : 8082[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bgau.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, should sound foolish. Since I am naive about networking.

Actually I was trying to make my Mac machine a cluster  master ( which happens to be a local broadband connected machine, without any domain.)

Works perfect when one AWS instance acts as Master and other AWS instance works as slave.